# Is there any way to hide a button but retain its functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have a button on navigation bar which when clicked, displays a dialog box.I want to keep this button invisible and whenever anyone clicks at the place where the button is placed it should open a dialog box i.e. it should remain fully functional even if it is invisible.I have tried `visibility:hidden` and `display:none` but nothing seems to provide me the desired result.Here is the fiddle -
https://jsfiddle.net/payalsuthar/58bw712t/5/
I want to hide the button in this fiddle and if i click at the place where the button is placed it should display the dialog box.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you will click hidden element?

Comment: i dont want to show this button to anyone but if i click at the place where the button is placed it should retain its functionality @Satpal..i will click at the place where the button is placed

Comment: UX will surely not be good, as a pop option when user click on __blank__ space

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/58bw712t/15/ try this opacity:0

Comment: Here, I hope it would help:

https://jsfiddle.net/58bw712t/11/

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/58bw712t/14/) check this demo

Comment: every one answered the question well but i selected the one which is short and simpler and the one who answered first ...and thanks for such quick response..@everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, you can use `opacity: 0`

Comment: Congrats ! You are the **FGITW** today :)

Answer (score 0):

Then instead of `button` use `div` and have onclick event defined for that div.
Since `div` will have no content, it will be like invisible and still be clickable.

```
<div id="clickMe" style="width:50px;height:50px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank label instead of button and you can achieve it like follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/58bw712t/10/

`<lable id="clickMe">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</lable>`

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
  $('#dialog1').dialog({
    buttons: {
      "yes": function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      },
      "no": function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: @Leothelion - yes agree with you. not that much good at CSS. So always think of JS approach. and this is how i thought of to solve this issue...`:)`!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

https://jsfiddle.net/58bw712t/12/

make the `appearance` none

```
#clickMe{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
   border: none;
   background: none;
   width : 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest including a note about browser support for `appearance`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
#clickMe{
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/58bw712t/16/)

Comment: This answer was already given then you should not repeat again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```css
#clickMe{
background-color: transparent;
color: transparent;
border: none;
}
```

Comment: or try opacity: 0;

Answer (score 0):

```
#clickMe{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This may help you.

Answer (score -2):

> [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/upvsftyq/2/)

You can use opacity 0 for hidden the button. And it is clickable.

This may help you. Working example is below.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/upvsftyq/2/`
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You should mention what you did in fiddle also this is not what op asked.

Comment: Even I used opacity 0 to the answer. I believe this is what op asked for.

Comment: Read back. OP wanted to div hide even before click but not after the click.

Comment: @Leothelion I have updated my answer. Thanks for clarification.